# How to clear ui-router hash on page change?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router 1.0b3 with angular 1.5.x.  Also using html5Mode(true). The hash's are not being used for the paths, they are just for the specific page it goes to.

I want to be able to go to 
http://example.com/app/page#tab3
route name: app.page

Then navigate to another page, say route name: app.another, it will take me to the page, but the # stays.  I don't want the # state to follow the navigation. Both pages need the same "app" parent.  If I go to another it should not go to "http://example.com/app/another#tab3" which is what is is doing.

It did not do this on ui-router 0.3.1

I tried removing the hash during the transition:
    $transitions.onBefore({exiting: 'app.**'}, function(trans) {
        trans.params("to")["#"] = null;
        $location.hash("");
    });

but that doesn't work at all.

Help?  I think this might be a bug, but I can't figure out a fix.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3245

Comment: Please try with `angular-ui-router` `1.0.0-rc.1`

Comment: It was indeed fixed in the rc.1

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I found solution to the problem of ui-router developers.

You can clear out the hash by clearing out the parameter (parameter named '#').

In templates:

```
<a ui-sref="app.tasks({'#': null})">text</a>
```

In javascript code:

```
$state.go('app.tasks', {'#': null});
```

P.S. I use **angular-ui-router**, version is **1.0.0-beta.3**

More information here:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3017